# What is the best way to modify the class for an input nested inside an ember component?

Tags: ember.js

So I have a simple ember component that looks something like this

```
<div class="my-wrapper">
  {{input value=password type="password" class="text-input"}}
</div>
```

The component itself is dead simple - something like this

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

Instead of "hard coding" the text-input class as I did above ... how can I instead "pass this in" when I use the component in my ember application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any parameters you pass into the component become properties on the component that are available to component's template.

So, you can do

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{ custom-input textClass="text-input"}}
</script>
```

Now, `textClass` is available to your component, so you can do

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/custom-input">
  <div class="my-wrapper">
    {{ input value=password type="password" class=textClass }}
  </div>
</script>
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zehinu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Awesome! I thought it was that easy but didn't have the exact syntax worked out :)